# Share path for two different controllers in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have two different controllers where one is called Movies and the other one is called Movie Articles. I really would like them both to be situated under the same path `/movies` so that I could have both movie titles and articles under that same path. I will only use #index for one of them but would like it accordingly in `routes.rb`

```
resources :movie_articles, :path => "movies", :only => [:index, :show]
resources :movies, :path => "movies", :only => [:show]
```

for url's such as

```
/movies/top-10-best-mafia-movies (article)
/movies/godfather-2 (movie)
```

Basically so that when Rails tries to look up "godfather-2" and does not find it in `movie_articles` it will continue to look for it under `movies`. I am quite sure this works for root_path but it does not seem to work for sub paths like this one.

Is it possible? How should it be done, in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible as "share two different controller actions under the one path" because rails needs to decide looking in the page url - which controller action should be called now? But you can do it under one action (in any of the controllers)

```
def show
  @record = MovieArticle.find_by(id: params[:id]) # use find_by to don't get 404
  @record ||= Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I confused it with having specified paths such as, translated to this example, get '/movies/this_specific_url', :controller => mycontroller#this_specific_action which I have used before. Your solution is a decent workaround for my problem though. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Christoffer happy to help :)